# multiple data storage (database and json) for the same model, how to do it?

Tags: laravel, oop, design-patterns

Ok, so am having multiple data storage for some models in my project, database storage which ganna save the user data, and a json storage which has a fixed data to compare with the user data.

so, am currently saving the json data in a property in the model after converting it to array, but it is so ANNOYING cause every model now is having a about 500 - 1000 line !

Am wondering, is there a design pattern or something like this which make it easier to relate these data to a model from another file ?

like having model which goal is to fetch the data from the database, and having entity which is related to this model and have this fixed json data on it.

BTW, am using Laravel framework, and my models are Eloquent ORM.

Example:

```
  class Building {
  protected $table = "buildings";

  //this data is so huge, but i need it to be related to this model so that i can access it from here.
  static $buildings = [
      'Castle' =>
            [
                'name' => 'Castle',
                'objectPath' => '/storage/3D/Land/models/Castle/CastleLevel1.fbx',
                'renderPath' => '/storage/3D/Land/models/Castle/Castle.png',
                'price' => 1000,
                'type' => 'castle',
                'levels' =>[
                    [
                        'upgradeTime' => 100,
                        'upgradeCost' => 100,
                        'requirements' => null
                    ],
                    [
                        'upgradeTime' => 100,
                        'upgradeCost' => 100,
                        'requirements' => null
                    ],
                ]
            ],
      // and so on ..
      ]

    function coordinates()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Coordinates::class, 'objectable');
    }

    //some functions here which relate this model to another models
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mysql as your relational DBMS you can use **JSON data type**. MySQL supports the native JSON data type since version 5.7.8. The native JSON data type allows you to store JSON documents more efficiently than the JSON text format in the previous versions. If you use previous versions of Mysql, then text datatype would be helpful and the only thing you need is a ``getCastle()``` function for example in your model to retrieve and convert your data to a dataset you need.

Comment: Yea that is a solution, but i don't believe it is the best practice. As I don't want to query the database every time I want to get castle information as this information is just fixed and it will not be changed.

Comment: OK then, after implementing JSON database, you can user Redis in order to cache results and omit repeated queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis